# How to counter the number of strings exceeding a certain number of characters in a string array. Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I get how to count the number of words in a string by extinguishing the spaces between words, but am confused of how to approach it when it asks for strings equal to or exceed a certain number of characters.

Complete the countLongWords() method below, which takes an 
array of Strings as its argument. This method returns an integer value 
representing the number of Strings in the array that are 5 or more characters 
long.

Comment: length() function of String?

Comment: What have you tried?  And where is "the countLongWords() method below"?  (I looked below).

Answer (score 2):

pseudocode

```
int count = 0
for str in stringArray
   if str.length() >=5 
      count++
return count
```

You can convert this to java

Answer (score 1):

Try to always think what you will do if you have a paper with this array of Strings written on it and want to count the number of Strings that satisfied this property.

Then it's very easy to translate that in a computer program.

1. Create a variable to hold the number of Strings with a length superior than 5
2. Loop through the element of your array
3. For each element, if it holds the property increment this variable
4. Return the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    if(array[i].length()>4){
        number++;
    }
}
return number;
```